# R: Correctly Using the "rmarkdown::render()" Function

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**My Question:** I am trying to learn how to use the `rmarkdown::render()`  function in R.

For example, suppose I have the following R Markdown Code:

````
---
title: "Storyboard Commentary"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
---

### A nice scatterplot here

```{r}
plot(cars, pch = 20)
grid()
```

---

Some commentary about Frame 1.

### A beautiful histogram on this board

```{r}
hist(faithful$eruptions, col = 'gray', border = 'white', main = '')
```

---

Some commentary about Frame 2.
````

I copied and pasted the above code into a Notepad document - and then saved this file as "test_render.Rmd".

Now, I want to use the `render()` function to execute this file, e.g. `rmarkdown::render("test_render.Rmd")` - but I am not sure how I can import this file into R **using code** (i.e. without manually clicking/pointing on the file).

The reason I am asking about this, is because I am using a computer at school where we only have the older GUI version of R (i.e. we do not have R Studio) and I would like to directly import an .Rmd file into R and use this `render()` function, and create the final result.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you execute `rmarkdown::render("test_render.Rmd")` on your R console and verify that the output html file (I think the file name should be `test_render.html`) exists in your current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to render the rmarkdown file and export it using the input and output arguments of render, i.e.

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "test_render.Rmd", output_file = "test_render.html")
```

It should save in your current working directory.